# Bypass page loader if Javascript is disabled

Tags: javascript, loader

I have an ajax loader that is displayed until all content on the page is loaded, however it is executed with javascript so if the user has javascript disabled the loader continues to display for an infinite amount of time.  Is there a way to either bypass this script or after a certain amount of 'loading time' just show the page?

Answer (score 0):

Set display to none for the loader by default and use javascript to set display to block when the page loads.